# Xamarin Android Player - Failed to initialize device

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-android-player

I just installed `Xamarin Android Player` and installed some of the devices as you can see on the following image but I get the error: `"Failed to initialize device..."` when I try to launch some of the virtual devices.

[image]

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: XAP is no longer supported.  You should use the Google Emulator, Genymotion, or the VS2015 emulator.

Comment: Are the VS2015 emulators installed by default?. On the emulators list (on VS2015) I think I see the ones I installed with the Android SDK Manager, but not sure. What is the most convenient free option?

Comment: the Google x86 emulators are now pretty good.  But Genymotion is probably easier to setup and use.  I haven't used the VS2015 one

Comment: But Genymotion is a paid emulator right?, I'm looking for a free one (with no trials). I think I got some warning about Google x86

Comment: Genymotion is free for personal use

Comment: ups, then I don't know why on every page I see the: "Buy" button and not a download link. Do you have a download link?

Comment: I believe you can create an account and login to download the personal version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Xamarin Android Player** is good, but it is *discontinued*. Your issue could be with the version of VirtualBox or a broken android image. Check do you use  VirtualBox 5.0.4. You could also try to re-download the android image for the problematic device.

But you have alternatives.

**Genymotion** is good, but it's *paid*. There is a free personal version, but if used by a professional, this violates the licence:

> "This [license](https://www.genymotion.com/legal/terms-and-conditions/) is granted to the end user only and exclusively in
>   connection with personal use, the end user is an individual, and not a
>   professional, who downloads the application for personal and private
>   needs, excluding commercial and professional environment."

**Visual Studio Android Emulator** plays very nice. And allows you run both Android and Windows 10 Mobile apps with full hardware acceleration without any tricky solutions.

> [Visual Studio Emulator for Android](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228279.aspx) is a component of the
>   cross-platform tools available in Visual Studio and will be installed
>   during a custom Visual Studio setup when you select Cross-Platform
>   Mobile Development, then Common Tools and Software Development Kits,
>   and then Visual Studio Emulator for Android.

Comment: just use the native Android Emulators or real devices. It works much more better nowadays (2017Feb)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it using the following steps:

1. Install a newer version of virtual box.
2. go to virtual box choose your device (nexus 10 in my case).
3. go to settings > system >  motherboard > base memory.
4. make base memory lower than 2 gigabytes.
    [image: [1]]
5. start xamarin android player after that and it worked for me.